Real-time flight data from FAA
I am using the SWIM Jumpstart kit from L3 Harris to retrieve real-time flight data. However, I suspect I am losing some data. For the real-time location of a flight, the time it takes to receive consecutive latitude and longitude updates for a particular aircraft is often around 30 seconds, and sometimes even up to 1 minute.
If somebody is using it, can they help me with this?

Have you tried contacting L3 Harris for help with problems with their product?  I've never been impressed with L3 Harris as a company, but maybe you'll have a better experience.
